# How to add one attribute column to another with a space between the two in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am wondering if it possible to add one attribute column to another with a space between the two in QGIS. I figured out you can add them together but I need a space between the texts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a string concatenator; It's this one `||` combined with a whitespace; It's `' '`

For example:

```
"field1"||' '||"field2"
```